# How to transfer object to function as it's class'es member

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, operator-overloading

For example: I have class "ListNode" which is linked list member, and i overloaded a [] operator for List class itself, but every time i need to get data from a node, i need to write `list[0]->getData()` or if I want to set new data, I need to write `list[0]->setData(*somedata*)`.
But I want to make it be able to work like for example like `list[0] = 5`, so first Node's data is setted to **6**. Same with functions. What should I do if I have Node which has **int** data, and I need to transfer it's data to a function, but without writing `Node->getData()` all the time?

Comment: You want to set 5 for object Node.?

Comment: @kanils_ yes, u're right

Comment: I guess you could override = operator for Node object to work in the way you want. Could you provide some code of your Node and ListNode?

Comment: As you are using c++ which is OOP language, it's not good to access class properties directly. Encapsulation https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/object-oriented-programming-OOP#:~:text=the%20following%20principles%3A-,Encapsulation,-.%20This%20principle%20states

Comment: Just make your `operator[]` return a reference to the element you want to access. Take `std::vector`'s `operator[]` as example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: @rturrado pretty cool idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `operator[]` return a reference to the element you want to access.

The example below is a simplified version of what would be a proper solution, including a `const` version for the `operator[]`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/7KKxPGEd5)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <stdexcept>  // range_error

struct Node
{
    int value{};
    Node* next{};
    int& operator[](size_t pos)
    {
        if (pos == 0) { return this->value; }
        else if (next == nullptr) { throw std::range_error{"out of bounds"}; }
        else { return (*next)[pos - 1]; }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node n5{5, nullptr};
    Node n4{4, &n5};
    Node n3{3, &n4};
    Node n2{2, &n3};
    Node list{1, &n2};

    try
    {
        std::cout << "list[3]: " << list[3] << "\n";
        list[3] = 25;
        std::cout << "list[3]: " << list[3] << "\n";
        std::cout << "list[13]: " << list[13] << "\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception& exc)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << exc.what() << ".\n";
    }
}
```